# Posting html data from angularjs to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, phpmailer

I have been trying to post HTML data from Angular to PHPMailer as JSON object and decoding them on PHP. However I can only send `h1, h2.... p` elements, when I use div / a etc as an object, it show two errors. `Anonymous function on posting` and `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:57948' is therefore not allowed access.` 
PHP file is on the remote server.

Here is my code:

Angular controller

```
$scope.documentContents = "<h2><a href='/index.html'> Div Contents with a tag </a><h2>"; // this gives error

// $scope.documentContents = "<h2> Div Contents with a tag <h2>"; this one works fine

$scope.sendEmailWithInfo = function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    $scope.dataToSend = {
        person: $scope.Fullname,
        contents: $scope.documentContents            
    };

    console.log($scope.dataToSend.contents);

    userServices.sendEmail($scope.dataToSend).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })

};
```

Angular Service

```
sendEmail: function (dataToSend) {

        return $http.post('http://....remote.php', dataToSend, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP Code

```html
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
@$person = $request->person; //used in template
@$contents = $request->contents;



$otherContents = "<h2>This is h2 html content</h2>";
$otherPerson= "Other Person";



$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();            
                         
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
     
$mail->Username = "email@email.com";                 
$mail->Password = "password";                           

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           

$mail->Port = 587;


ob_start();
require("template.php");
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();





$mail->setFrom('email here', $person);

$mail->addReplyTo('email here', 'First Last');

$mail->addAddress('email', 'John Doe');

$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer sendmail test';

$mail->msgHTML($html);


$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem could be that quotes you use `'` - in

```
<h2><a href='/index.html'> Div Contents with a tag </a><h2>
```

interferes with JSON quotes, so if your try to use following:

```
$scope.documentContents = "<h2><a href='/index.html'> Div Contents with a tag </a><h2>";
 $scope.dataToSend = {
        person: $scope.Fullname,
        contents: $scope.documentContents.replace(/'/g, '&quot;');          
    };
```

Comment: It's still is the same. Anyway, when php file has been moved to local server, it accepts post but shows Fatal error, can't convert to string on php line 3. so $contents is not converted to string.

Comment: _<b>Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\docurate-xampp\pdf\template.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br /> _

Comment: data was being passed as object. `$scope.dataToSend = {
            person: $scope.Fullname,
            contents: $scope.documentContents.outerHTML       //outerHTML has solved the problem converting it to string.  
        };`